# Problem in @ somebody in the comments!

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Currently, I am facing strange problems in @ somebody in the comments. The following is a list where I am unable to @ the posters.

Eg:

1) [Why was Abe sent from the future and where is Abe in the present?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8772/why-was-abe-sent-from-the-future-and-where-is-abe-in-the-present)
   Here I cant @iandotkelly

2) [Did Kareena Kapoor charge Aamir Khan for talking to her?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8648/did-kareena-kapoor-charge-aamir-khan-for-talking-to-her/8783#8783)
   Here I cant @user221287

3) [What kind of job three friends do in Pyaar Ka Punchnama?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8206/what-kind-of-job-three-friends-do-in-pyaar-ka-punchnama)
   Here I cant @somnamth muluk

Please mods do look into the problem. It is quite troubling me as I try to be very polite during comments and @somebody is a nice way to be polite!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a bug, it's the way the system is designed. The full details are given in [this post on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), but basically, when you're commenting on a question or answer, the author of the question or answer is always notified of your comment, even without using `@username`. If there is not already an existing comment discussion on the post (roughly speaking), if you start your comment with an @-notification, it will be stripped off because it's not useful.

These @-notifications don't really contribute to politeness all that much, they're only there for convenience. Politeness on SE is more about what you don't say than what you do say.